# prizepicks api scrap not providing names

Tags: python, api, web-scraping

how can i make it so that it grabs the players name

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
pp_props_url = 'https://api.prizepicks.com/projections?league_id=7&per_page=250&single_stat=true'
headers = {
'Connection': 'keep-alive',
'Accept': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/106.0.0.0 Safari/537.36',
'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials': 'true',
'Sec-Fetch-Site': 'same-origin',
'Sec-Fetch-Mode': 'cors',
'Referer': 'https://app.prizepicks.com/',
'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.9'}

response = requests.get(url=pp_props_url, headers=headers).json()
df = pd.json_normalize(response,
                       record_path =['data'])

df.to_csv('player_props_20221030.csv')
```

so once it prints i want it to include the player name aswell

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```py
import requests
import pandas as pd

pp_props_url = (
    "https://api.prizepicks.com/projections?league_id=7&per_page=250&single_stat=true"
)
headers = {
    "Connection": "keep-alive",
    "Accept": "application/json; charset=UTF-8",
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/106.0.0.0 Safari/537.36",
    "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials": "true",
    "Sec-Fetch-Site": "same-origin",
    "Sec-Fetch-Mode": "cors",
    "Referer": "https://app.prizepicks.com/",
    "Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate, br",
    "Accept-Language": "en-US,en;q=0.9",
}

response = requests.get(url=pp_props_url, headers=headers).json()

players = {}
for d in response["included"]:
    players[d["id"]] = d["attributes"]

data = []
for d in response['data']:
    data.append({
        **d['attributes'],
        'name': players[d['relationships']['new_player']['data']['id']]['name']
    })

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
print(df.head())
```

Prints:

```
                  board_time custom_image description end_time flash_sale_line_score  is_promo  line_score projection_type  rank  refundable                 start_time      stat_type    status tv_channel                 updated_at          name
0  2023-04-18T19:10:00-04:00         None         ATL     None                  None     False         0.5     Single Stat  2001        True  2023-04-21T19:10:00-04:00  Blocked Shots  pre_game       None  2023-04-19T21:37:05-04:00  Jayson Tatum
1  2023-04-18T19:10:00-04:00         None         ATL     None                  None     False         9.5     Single Stat  2001        True  2023-04-21T19:10:00-04:00       Rebounds  pre_game       None  2023-04-19T21:37:58-04:00  Jayson Tatum
2  2023-04-21T13:54:12-04:00         None         BOS     None                  None     False        19.5     Single Stat  2001        True  2023-04-21T19:00:00-04:00   FG Attempted  pre_game       None  2023-04-21T13:56:28-04:00    Trae Young
3  2023-04-19T19:10:00-04:00         None         ATL     None                  None     False        49.5   Fantasy Score  2001        True  2023-04-21T19:10:00-04:00  Fantasy Score  pre_game       None  2023-04-20T18:47:36-04:00  Jayson Tatum
4  2023-04-18T19:10:00-04:00         None         ATL     None                  None     False        34.5     Single Stat  2001        True  2023-04-21T19:10:00-04:00       Pts+Asts  pre_game       None  2023-04-19T23:48:34-04:00  Jayson Tatum
```